# Proof divergence of a kind of harmonic series

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need to proof that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+2}= \infty$ . I tried to use the comparison criterium with the harmonic series but since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+2} 
 <\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ , I can't say that the smaller series is divergent because bigger one diverges, so, I got confused. How can I compare $\frac{1}{n+2}$ with something smaller? Or how can I manipulate the harmonic series to conclude something?

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n+2}$ converged to $L$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ would converge to $1+\frac12+L$

Answer (score 3):

$n+2 \leq 3n$ for all $n$. So $\sum \frac 1 {n+2} \geq \sum \frac 1 {3n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply expanding out some terms and see if there is a connection. We know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+...$$
and that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac13+\frac14+ ...$$
So you can see that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}.$$
I'll leave the rest to you. The other suitable, more common test is the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** We have
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

If your series converges, then also the harmonic series has to converge since $3n \geq n + 2$. Thus the assumption was wrong and your series has to diverge.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$\sum_1^\infty \frac {1}{n}=\infty$$

Note that $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac {1}{n+2} =1/3+1/4+....=$$

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac {1}{n} -1-1/2=\infty -3/2 =\infty $$

Answer (score 0):

This is another comparison test, compute the limit of the reason
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+2}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n+2}=1\neq 0$$
If the limit is $\neq 0$, then both series converge or both diverge, but we know the harmonic series diverges. Thus, the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}$$
also diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing:

Consider

$S_n= \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{n}} \dfrac{1}{k+2}$;

$R_n=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=3}^{n+2}}\dfrac{1}{k}$;

$R_n=S_n$;

But $R_n$ diverges for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Hence?